# Play Framework: Post image to imageshack using WS

Tags: java, file, api, post, playframework

I am trying to `POST` an image to imageshack using [their API](http://code.google.com/p/imageshackapi/wiki/ImageshackAPI) and Play Framework's [WSRequest](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/1.2.3/play/libs/WS.WSRequest.html) object.

My code is as follows:

```
public static void upload( Picture picture ) throws Exception {

    //set file parameter - in this case the image
    WS.FileParam fp = new WS.FileParam( picture.asFile, "fileupload");

    //set other parameters
    Map<String,Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    params.put( "optsize", "resample" );
    params.put( "rembar", "yes" );
    params.put( "public", "no" );
    params.put( "a_username", username );
    params.put( "a_password", password );
    params.put( "key", a_key );

    //POST request
    Document doc = WS.url( "http://www.imageshack.us/upload_api.php" )
        .setHeader( "Content-Type", picture.contentType )
        .mimeType( "multipart/form-data" )
        .params( params )
        .files( fp )
        .post()
        .getXml();
}
```

However, I always reveive the following response from imageshack:

***Sorry, but we've detected that unexpected data is received. Required parameter 'fileupload' is missing or your post is not multipart/form-data.***

I have tried sending the file as a parameter using a byte array:

```
params.put( "fileupload", Base64.encode( picture.asBytes )  )
```

But this also results in the same response from Imageshack.

This is driving me mad. Can anyone point out where I am going wrong or possibly point me in the direction of a better solution? Thanks.

---

#### The cause

After a bit of research I found that I had neglected a bit of important information from this question....I am including the Google App Engine module within my app.

According to the [Play Framework Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/play-framework/browse_thread/thread/96c2d575fbd62381/df2c47867bbe8508?lnk=gst&q=WS+google+app+engine#df2c47867bbe8508) the code associated with attaching Files to a WS request when using GAE is actually just commented out. Hence the reason it just doesn't work. So no error thrown for you and no indication why it doesn't work...you just have to work it out.

I have accepted @Gary's answer as it is the correct way to upload an image to imageshack using WS - just not when using GAE.

Comment: I have upgraded to Play 1.2.4 with no success

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you need to specify the content type or mime type directly.

I used the following code to upload successfully.

```
WS.FileParam fp = new WS.FileParam(
      new File("d:\\workspace\\ImageShackTest\\sample_picture.png"), "fileupload");

    Map<String,Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    params.put( "optsize", "resample" );
    params.put( "rembar", "yes" );
    params.put( "public", "yes" );
    //params.put( "a_username", username );
    //params.put( "a_password", password );
    params.put( "key", API_KEY );

    //POST request
    Document doc = WS.url( "http://www.imageshack.us/upload_api.php" )
        .params( params )
        .files( fp )
        .post()
        .getXml();
```

I think when you attach a file to a request it automatically decides its going to be multipart/form-data.

This is my entire controller (except for the API Key)

```
package controllers;

import play.*;
import play.mvc.*;
import java.util.*;
import models.*;
import play.libs.*;
import java.io.File;

public class Application extends Controller {

    public static void index() { render(); }

    private static final String API_KEY = "API KEY REMOVED TO PROTECT THE INNOCENT";

    public static void tryUpload() {
        WS.FileParam fp = new WS.FileParam( new File("d:\\workspace\\ImageShackTest\\sample_picture.png"), "fileupload");

        Map<String,Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        params.put( "optsize", "resample" );
        params.put( "rembar", "yes" );
        params.put( "public", "yes" );
        params.put( "key", API_KEY );

        String doc = WS.url( "http://www.imageshack.us/upload_api.php" )
            .params( params )
            .files( fp )
            .post()
            .getString();

        System.out.println(doc);

        index();
    }
}
```

and this is the application.conf file

```
# This is the main configuration file for the application.
# ~~~~~
application.name=ImageShackTest
application.mode=dev
%prod.application.mode=prod
application.secret=JIVQE8y3y1lCzXRGprFJvoXBdi8Jpa8qE1U1mBIooLLOOYk5yyhAI5cxbEf4q4pl
date.format=yyyy-MM-dd
attachments.path=data/attachments
mail.smtp=mock
```

I didn't make any other changes.  Just browsed to http://localhost:9000/Application.tryUpload and could see the success XML on the play console.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am still receiving the same error message. What version of Play are you using?

Comment: I have upgraded to Play 1.2.4 and that has not helped. Are there any details in your config file that you have changed?

Comment: One thing I did think of, I don't know the Picture class that well.  Try uploading an image file directly.  It might be that the Picture.asFile doesn't name it properly?

Comment: +1 for all the extra info :) In the test I am trying to upload a file straight from my hard drive just to rule out any potential coding issues but this does not work. I am going to create a new app that does nothing else but post to ImageShack and see if it is possibly something to do with my app. I am using the GAE module so it is possible that this has a negative effect.

Comment: Excellent. This works when I am not using GAE. I have also found from a bit of research that the file attachment part of Web Socket is actually commented out since it doesn't work as part of GAE. They prob should have mentioned that somewhere. Thanks for the help!!! I'll accept this as the answer and give you the bounty since it does actually work in respect to my question!

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the content type header incorrectly.

Instead of this:

```
.setHeader( "Content-Type", picture.contentType )
```

Try this:

```
.setHeader( "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data" )
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not seem to work either. In the `.setHeader` I am applying the content type of the image and in the `.mimeType` I am setting that the information was sent through a form. I thought this was the correct way to do it, but this is the first time I have attempted a post like this. I have tried switching them and leaving out the image content type but neither of these seem to work for me.